# Можно ли как-то не принимать пользовательские настройки размера шрифта и масштабирования?

Tags: android, settings

В моём приложении начинает плыть интерфейс, если сделать шрифт крупнее или увеличить масштаб.

Я конечно могу сделать размеры интерфейса dp вместо sp, но в моём приложении есть WebView, которое открывает страницу в интернете и там весь интерфейс тоже плывёт.

Можно-ли как-то отклонять пользовательские настройки шрифта и масштабирования, чтобы они не влияли на моё приложение и оно брало стандартные настройки?

**Так выглядит интерфейс при изменении настроек на самый крупный шрифт:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Так должно быть:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**По коду самого WebView ничего особенного, если кратко, то вот:**

```
wv = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        settings.setUserAgentString("settings.getUserAgentString());
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // включает поддержку JavaScript
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // устанавливает, включен ли API хранения DOM
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true); // включает доступ к URL-адресам контента в WebView
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true); // включает доступ к файлам в WebView
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8"); // устанавливает кодировку utf-8
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(this), "stb");
        wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Comment: webView.getSettings().getDefaultFontSize(); и чем вам dp вместо sp не нравится, хорошо работает же

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, он не нравится тем, что я не могу этот dp проставить на странице, который открывает мой браузер, встроенный в приложении, а на этой странице тоже всё плывёт из-за этих настроек... Спасибо

Comment: покажите тогда как в webView меняете dp всего вашего приложения. Плывет webView или страница на которой он? Приведите пример кода, проще будет ответить на вопрос.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, сама страница в размере не увеличивается, просто внутри кнопок увеличивается шрифт и из-за этого слова подрезаются. Нужно сделать так, чтобы приложение использовало стандартные настройки телефона, а не пользовательские. Скрины интерфейса щас приложу к вопросу